# for loop returning wrong value

Tags: c#

This is probably a school boy mistake, but I cannot work it out/get the correct results to return.

My for loop is a follows:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int a = 1; a < numberOfRooms; a++)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("<div id=HotelRoom{0}>", a)).AppendLine();
    sb.Append(string.Format("<p>Room {0}</p>", a)).AppendLine();
    sb.Append(string.Format("<select id=room{0}>", a)).AppendLine();
    sb.Append("<option value=\"0\">Adults (18+)</option>").AppendLine();
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("<option value={0}>{0}</option>", i)).AppendLine();
    }
    sb.Append("</select>").AppendLine();

    sb.Append(string.Format("<select id=ChildCountRoom{0}>", a)).AppendLine();
    sb.Append("<option value=\"0\">Children 0 - 17</option>").AppendLine();
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("<option value={0}>{0}</option>", i)).AppendLine();
    }
    sb.Append("</select>").AppendLine();
    sb.Append("</div>");
    sb.Append(string.Format("<div id=\"NumberOfChildrenRoom{0}\"></div>",a)).AppendLine();
}
return sb.ToString();
```

With the code above even if I pass in the value 2 to numberOfRooms it loops twice returning 2 records, even though the loop starts at 1

The inner loop works correctly i.e.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
```

return 8

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
```

return 3

Can anyone with a fresh pair of eyes see what I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend to run the code step-by-step via debugger.

Comment: did you check if numberOfRooms is still `2` at the point the loop starts? maybe something else is incrementing it.

Comment: Have checked in debugger, loops twice, gets to bottom of loop then starts at top again. numberOfRooms is 2

Comment: Side note: Consider using HtmlAgilityPack if you need to read/generate HTML in console app, or normal ASP.Net ASPX/CSHTML pages for web sites.

Comment: try to replace outer look with this:`int numberOfRooms = 1;
foreach(int a in Enumerable.Range(1,numberOfRooms))
{ 
}`

Comment: In your outermost loop instead of `a < numberOfRooms;` say `a < 2;` and see if that sorts out.

Comment: BTW, your variable name and loop combined + you requirement are a little bit confusing: `int numberOfRooms=2` sounds like there should be 2 loop iterations, not one. This makes code error-prone.

Comment: is numberOfRooms accessed by another thread?

Comment: Are you certain that your outermost loop is same as posted in question. I mean it shouldn't like `for (int a = 1; a <= numberOfRooms; a++)`?

Comment: I suggest to clean and rebuild the solution. Then step inside the loop with the debugger and then open your Debug Window called Auto. Look at the values of numberOfRows and a. Continue step by step and look if something change in these two variables. As shown above, this code cannot loop 2 times.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan thanks for the reply, the reason it starts at 2 is because I have a static list in the page for room 1, so the next page would be room 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

The code *you've supplied* does what you've coded it to do: it executes the body of the `for` loop one less time than the value of `numberOfRooms`.

[And you **do** realize that you're writing, not one, but *two* sibling `<div>` elements each time the body of the `for` loop is executed, right?]

So, for

- `n=1`, I get an empty string as the result, since the body of the `for` loop is never executed.
- `n=2`, the body of the for loop is executed just once and generates this:

  ```
  <div id=HotelRoom1>
    <p>Room 1</p>
    <select id=room1>
      <option value="0">Adults (18+)</option>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
      <option value=4>4</option>
      <option value=5>5</option>
      <option value=6>6</option>
      <option value=7>7</option>
      <option value=8>8</option>
    </select>
    <select id=ChildCountRoom1>
      <option value="0">Children 0 - 17</option>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="NumberOfChildrenRoom1"></div>
  ```
- `n=3`, the body of the `for` loop is executed twice, generating

  ```
  <div id=HotelRoom1>
    <p>Room 1</p>
    <select id=room1>
      <option value="0">Adults (18+)</option>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
      <option value=4>4</option>
      <option value=5>5</option>
      <option value=6>6</option>
      <option value=7>7</option>
      <option value=8>8</option>
    </select>
    <select id=ChildCountRoom1>
      <option value="0">Children 0 - 17</option>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="NumberOfChildrenRoom1"></div>

  <div id=HotelRoom2>
    <p>Room 2</p>
    <select id=room2>
      <option value="0">Adults (18+)</option>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
      <option value=4>4</option>
      <option value=5>5</option>
      <option value=6>6</option>
      <option value=7>7</option>
      <option value=8>8</option>
    </select>
    <select id=ChildCountRoom2>
      <option value="0">Children 0 - 17</option>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="NumberOfChildrenRoom2"></div>
  ```

To get this I pasted your code into Visual Studio, wrapped it in a simple console app, and did a little refactoring to make it more readable,thus:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
  class Program
  {
    static string GenerateHtml( int numberOfRooms )
    {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      for ( int a = 1 ; a < numberOfRooms ; a++ )
      {
        sb.AppendFormat( "<div id=HotelRoom{0}>"                            , a ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "  <p>Room {0}</p>"                                , a ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "  <select id=room{0}>"                            , a ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "    <option value=\"0\">Adults (18+)</option>"        ).AppendLine() ;
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < 9 ; i++ )
        {
        sb.AppendFormat( "    <option value={0}>{0}</option>"               , i ).AppendLine() ;
        }
        sb.AppendFormat( "  </select>"                                          ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "  <select id=ChildCountRoom{0}>"                  , a ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "    <option value=\"0\">Children 0 - 17</option>"     ).AppendLine() ;
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
        {
        sb.AppendFormat( "    <option value={0}>{0}</option>"               , i ).AppendLine() ;
        }
        sb.AppendFormat( "  </select>"                                          ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "</div>"                                               ).AppendLine() ;
        sb.AppendFormat( "<div id=\"NumberOfChildrenRoom{0}\"></div>"       , a ).AppendLine() ;
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
    static void Main()
    {
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
      {
        Console.WriteLine() ;
        Console.WriteLine("=== {0} =============================================================" , i ) ;
        string html = GenerateHtml(i) ;
        Console.WriteLine( html ) ;
        Console.WriteLine("=====================================================================") ;
      }
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas, can you explain how you got the data, I have stepped through the code and it returns: {<div id=HotelRoom2>
<p>Room 2</p>
<select id=room2>
<option value="0">Adults (18+)</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
<option value=6>6</option>
<option value=7>7</option>
<option value=8>8</option>
</select>
<select id=ChildCountRoom2>
<option value="0">Children 0 - 17</option>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
</select>
}

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson: see my amended answer for details.

Comment: Hi Nicholas just created a console app and you are correct, but in my MVC website, my default value for numberOfRooms = 2, I have run test in MVC up to 8 rooms, numberOfRooms = 8 and it works as expected. starts at 2 and counts up. Could the reason be your: for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i ). As i only have the 1 loop and that is the code shown. **Look forward** to your feedback as you have more experience than me